# SSRS report working very slow in report server

Tags: performance, reporting-services, server, report, execution

I have a SSRS report having 10 parameters displaying the data from a single SQL server table.
Report is showing around 400000 rows and 64 columns. When I am executing this report from SSDT it is working fine, but when I deployed it to the report server it is returning the result set ne 1 min for first execution and after that when I am running it without refreshing the browser it is taking too long time to display the data. Anyone have any idea why this is happening.
Below is the query I am using:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Get_Individual_File_Detail&Total_Records] 
(
   @RecordType NVARCHAR(10) = '',
   @PreferenceType NVARCHAR(400) = '',
   @RecordID NVARCHAR(4000) = '',
   --@RecordID INT = '',
   @CountryCode VARCHAR(4000) = '',
   @State NVARCHAR(4000) = '',
   @VIPFlag NVARCHAR(10) = '',
   @Paperflag NVARCHAR(10) = '',
   @GoGreenFlag NVARCHAR(10) = '',
   @AdjustmentRate NVARCHAR(40) = '',
   @RefundRateCode NVARCHAR(50) = '',
   @customernumber NVARCHAR(50) = '',
   @TotalCheckAmount FLOAT = ''
)   

--WITH RECOMPILE
AS
BEGIN
    
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Finaldata') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #Finaldata


DECLARE @PreferenceTypeXML AS XML
SET @PreferenceTypeXML = CAST(('<A>'+REPLACE(@PreferenceType,',' ,'</A><A>')+'</A>') AS XML)

DECLARE @RecordIDXML AS XML
SET @RecordIDXML = CAST(('<A>'+REPLACE(@RecordID,',' ,'</A><A>')+'</A>') AS XML)


DECLARE @AdjustmentRateXML AS XML
SET @AdjustmentRateXML = CAST(('<A>'+REPLACE(@AdjustmentRate,',' ,'</A><A>')+'</A>') AS XML)

SELECT  CASE WHEN CAST([Aon Refrence No] AS INT) >= 0  AND CAST([Aon Refrence No] AS INT) <= 199999 THEN 'CHECK' 
             WHEN CAST([Aon Refrence No] AS INT) >= 5000000  AND CAST([Aon Refrence No] AS INT) <= 5999999 THEN 'CHECK' 
             WHEN CAST([Aon Refrence No] AS INT) >= 7000000  AND CAST([Aon Refrence No] AS INT) <= 7099999 THEN 'CHECK' 
             WHEN CAST([Aon Refrence No] AS INT) >= 3000000 AND CAST([Aon Refrence No] AS INT) <= 3999999 THEN 'CREDIT ON ACCT' 
             WHEN CAST([Aon Refrence No] AS INT) >= 2000000  AND CAST([Aon Refrence No] AS INT) <= 2199999 THEN 'GVUL INVEST' 
             WHEN CAST([Aon Refrence No] AS INT) >= 1000000  AND CAST([Aon Refrence No] AS INT) <= 1199999 THEN 'EFT'
             WHEN CAST([Aon Refrence No] AS INT) >= 1200000  AND CAST([Aon Refrence No] AS INT) <= 1300000 THEN 'ACH' ELSE 'Blank'
        END AS [Preference Type],  [Customer No],[Social Security No],[Aon Refrence No],[Aon Ref Suffix],[Identifier],[Name],[Address],[Address2],[Address3],[City],[State],[Zip 5],[Zip 4],[Country]
           ,[YTD Earned Premium-AS400],[Refund Rate Code],[Check Amount],[Interest Amount],[Tax Amount],[Refund Rate],[Foreign Mail],[Pay Mode],[Pay Mode Description],[Assignee Name]
           ,[Plan Year],[Record ID],[Plan Code],[Plan Description],[VIP Flag],[Legal Flag],[Bank Transaction Code],[Check Number],[Transaction Date],[YTD Earned Premium],[Spouse Bonus]
           ,[EFT Bonus],[Dependent Coverage],[ERP Bonus],[Rate Class],[Masked SSN],[Adjustment Rate],[Premium Credit],[Processed],[Bank Name],[Bank Holder Name],[Routing No]
           ,[Bank Account No],[Bank Account Type],[Unique ID1],[Unique ID2],[Unique ID3],[Unique ID4],[Unique ID5],[Company],[Ach Pref Bonus],[Total Check Amount],[Assigned]
           , [Go Green Flag],[Paper Flag],[WellOne Bonus],[Wellness Score Bonus],[Email Address]
INTO #Finaldata FROM [dbo].[Table] (NOLOCK)

--CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX tempndx ON #Finaldata ([Refund Rate Code],[Preference Type],[Identifier],[Record ID],[VIP Flag],[Country],[State],[Adjustment Rate],[Customer No],[Paper Flag],[Go Green Flag]);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_tempndx ON #Finaldata ([Customer No], [Social Security No], [Aon Refrence No], [Aon Ref Suffix], Identifier)
--Get final result

SELECT  * FROM #Finaldata (NOLOCK)
WHERE 
  (ISNULL(@RecordType,'All') = 'All'  OR [Identifier] = @RecordType)
  AND  [Preference Type] IN (SELECT A.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS [Column] FROM @PreferenceTypeXML.nodes('A') AS FN(A))
 AND (ISNULL(@RefundRateCode,'') = ''  OR [Refund Rate Code] = @RefundRateCode)
 AND (ISNULL(@RecordID,'All') = 'All'  OR [Record ID] IN (SELECT A.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS [Column] FROM @RecordIDXML.nodes('A') AS FN(A)))
 AND (ISNULL(@VIPFlag,'All') = 'All' OR [VIP Flag] = @VIPFlag)
 AND (ISNULL(@CountryCode,'All') = 'All' OR [Country] =@CountryCode)
 AND (ISNULL(@State,'All') = 'All'  OR [State] = @State)
 AND (ISNULL(@AdjustmentRate,'All') = 'All' OR [Adjustment Rate] IN (SELECT A.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS [Column] FROM @AdjustmentRateXML.nodes('A') AS FN(A)))
 AND (ISNULL(@Paperflag,'All') = 'All' OR [Paper Flag] = @Paperflag)
 AND (ISNULL(@GoGreenFlag,'All') = 'All' OR [Go Green Flag] = @GoGreenFlag)
 AND (ISNULL(@customernumber,'') = '' OR CAST([Customer No] AS INT) = @customernumber)
 AND (ISNULL(@TotalCheckAmount,'') = '' OR [Total Check Amount] > @TotalCheckAmount)
 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Finaldata') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #Finaldata
    

END
GO
```

Query executing perfectly find from the visual studio and giving output in 23 sec with all the parameters. When I am executing the report from the report server first time it is giving me output in 2 min and after that if I executing the same report with same parameter it is taking to long time

Comment: You'll probably need to edit your question and show the dataset query, parameters and how they are used. My guess would be parameter sniffing but without more info it's impossible to be much help.